# I'm trying to intsall Ubuntu to a (Samsung) NP300E4C laptop but can't access BIOS

Tags: laptop, live-usb, samsung, bios

The computer is currently running Windows (7).

I've tried tapping and holding down F2 but it just boots to windows.

I googled to see if i can find people with similar issues but found none.

I'm wondering if I have to change some setting some where while running windows.
or if you guys can tell me how to allow USB boot without going to BIOS that would help.

Comment: "while running windows" ehm and you ask us that why? ;) Windows questions are better asked on http://superuser.com/

Comment: *This is an **Ubuntu** issue, they are trying to install it.*

Answer (score 1):

For Samsung NP300E4C ..

from: [Samsung NP300E5C User Manual > Page 75](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/421065/Samsung-Np300e5c.html?page=75#manual)

> Turn the computer on. Immediately press the F2 key several times.

*You may just have to keep trying.* You don't need to change boot-order, as generally better results can be obtained by manually selecting boot device.

---

More modern laptops, with **Windows 8.1**, do actively prevent you from accessing BIOS. But, access can be obtained through 'Recovery Menu' within **Windows 8.1**. *This should not be an issue on your laptop (given its age).*

---

**UPDATE**

Yes, I understood you were on **Windows 7**.

Please review: [superuser.com > cant access BIOS .. on Samsung .. NP270E5V](https://superuser.com/questions/656956/i-cant-access-the-bios-setup-using-f2-key-on-samsung-laptop-model-np270e5v)

Suggestions:

- Try <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> instead;
- Try <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> (holding down <kbd>Fn</kbd>, then pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>);
- Try <kbd>F2</kbd>, after holding down <kbd>Esc</kbd> during power-on/startup;
- or contact Samsung support ..

Comment: the thing is i cant choose to boot from usb and its a wind 7

Answer (score 1):

Try **repeatedly** pressing F2 while starting the system up instead of just holding it.

I'm pretty sure your on the right track with F2, but if you don't see that on screen please check your laptop manual.